# How to use random id of same model in laravel factories?

Tags: laravel, factory

I am trying to build a simple page hierarchy for a website in Laravel and want to create a factory for my Page model. A column in Page is 'parent_id' which I want to populate with the id of another random page that has just been created as part of the factory run.

First thing to note is I already have one default page in the db before the factory is run.

So for example, If I use my factory to create 10 pages.

```
Page::factory()->times(10)->create();
```

What I WANT to happen is:

- The first page created will look in the pages table and pick a page at random, then use that id in the parent_id column. There is only one page in the db at this point, so that id is used
- For the second page, there are now two pages in the database, so one is picked at random and the id is used in the parent_id column
- For the third page, there are now three pages in the database, so one is picked at random and the id is used in the parent_id column
- etc. etc.

My (reduced) factory looks like this

```
public function definition(): array
{
    return [
        'name'        => $this->faker->sentence(5),
        'url'         => $this->faker->url,
        'parent_id'   => Page::all()->random()->id,
    ];
}
```

But this only gets the id of the first page that is in the DB before the factory is run. All factory built pages have the same parent_id.

How can I update the factory so the parent_id is different for each newly created page?

Comment: Use [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#factory-callbacks](`afterCreating`) callback for parent_id population

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try parent_id from closure function.

```
'parent_id'   => function() {
    return Page::count() > 0 ? Page::all()->random()->id : null;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a [factory callback](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#factory-callbacks) to solve this problem which allows you to perform additional tasks after making or creating a model.

```
class PageFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Page::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->sentence(5),
            'url' => $this->faker->url,
        ];
    }

    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Page $page) {
           
            $parentPage = Page::inRandomOrder()->first();


            if ($parentPage) {
                $page->parent_id = $parentPage->id;
                $page->save();
            }
        });
    }
}
```